# Как своё приложение открыть поверх других?

Tags: android

Запускаю своё приложение, написанное под Android. Сворачиваю или открываю поверх любое другое.

Как по событию, открыть своё приложение поверх других приложений?

Comment: Вообще вопрос слишком общий. Напишите подробнее чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Как открыть своё приложение поверх других приложений? Путь по таймеру

Comment: Используйте AlarmManager для посылки Intent, а далее как в моём ответе.

Answer (score 1):

1. Зарегистрировать в манифесте [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
2. В классе вашего **BroadcastReceiver** поймать некий **Intent**
3. Запустить **Activity**

Comment: BroadcastReceiver - широковещательные сообщения, кому их посылать? Приложение их должно послать самому себе чтоли?

Comment: Итак, по таймеру с помощью AlarmManager посылаю Intent, его ловлю в BroadcastReceiver и запускаю Activity? Пытаюсь переварить почему так сложно...

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver универсален и им можно разные интенты ловить. Например о запуске устройства.

Comment: А можно сразу по таймеру напрямую отобразить Activity, указав ей - "откройся поверх всех окон"?

Comment: Да, AlarmManager использует PenginIntent, коий может вызвать как BroadcastReceiver так и Service или Activity. При этом в Intent можно задать разные флаги, кои определят как именно запустить Activity.

Comment: Вы делаете шабашки? Если да, то как с вами связаться?

Comment: Что такое шабашки?..

Comment: ну фриланс-работы...

Comment: Не-а) По крайней мере не чрез спутниковый интернет)

Comment: Смогли бы помочь сделать такое окошко поверх других приложений за деньги? )

Comment: Почему бы вам не обратиться на фриланс-биржу?

Comment: Пока не нашлись кандидаты, ктоб смог)